# can't deploy git repository to dokku instance (fatal: {reponame} does not appear to be a git repository)

Tags: git, ssh, digital-ocean, dokku

I'm trying to deploy my application which is located on my local git repo to my dokku instance on digitalocean.

**Zone file**

```
$ORIGIN mydomain.com.
$TTL 1800
...
mydomain.com. 1800 IN A 11.22.33.44
www.mydomain.com. 1800 IN CNAME mydomain.com.
*.mydomain.com. 1800 IN A 11.22.33.44
test.mydomain.com. 1800 IN A 11.22.33.44
```

I intend to deploy my app on `test.mydomain.com`

**dokku setup**

I used the dokku image on digitalocean to setup the server, which currently runns on dokku `v0.4.15`, and tried to deploy my app according to [the guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-dokku-one-click-install-image-to-deploy-your-app) which is obviousely obsolete, however, I didn't find a more recent one.

**ssh setup**

I also set up the SSH keys and config file, so I'm able to log in to my dokku instance over SSH for both users ***root*** and ***dokku***:

`ssh {username}@test.localhome.ch` `// works`

**local ssh config file**

```
Host          mydomain.com test.mydomain.com
        HostName       11.22.33.44
        IdentityFile   ~/.ssh/mydomain
        PreferredAuthentications publickey
```

**deployment**

When I try to deploy my git repo:

```
git remote add dokku dokku@test.mydomain.com:test
git push dokku master
```

it would throw me

```
fatal: 'test' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What did I miss?

**Edit 1**

I also ssh'ed into the server and added the dokku app

```
ssh dokku@mydomain.com
dokku apps:create test
```

The app seems to have been added correctly server-side..

```
dokku@mydomain:~$ dokku apps
=====> My Apps
test
```

.. however, the push is still failing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wasn't able to solve the problem for the oneclick dokku-installation on digitalocean, so instead, I had to setup the instance manually, which wasn't that hard.

**Dokku setup**

1. Create a new `Ubuntu 14.04.4 x64` droplet.
2. Don't setup the RSA yet, use password authentication to login to the droplet.
3. Install [dokku](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/installation/):

   wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dokku/dokku/v0.5.2/bootstrap.sh
   sudo DOKKU_TAG=v0.5.2 bash bootstrap.sh

**Setup RSA**

*Assumption:* We don't use the default RSA key (usually `.ssh/id_rsa.pub`), but instead a custom one: `.ssh/custom.pub`

1. add the public key using the following one-liner

   cat ~/.ssh/custom.pub | ssh root@mydomain.com "sudo sshcommand acl-add dokku custom-identifier"

*For more information please refer to [this page](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/29533043-new-app-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository)*

**Deploy repo**

Deploy your repo, for a quick test [this example](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/application-deployment/) can be used.
Also, the DNS need to be setup accordingly (if the apps name is `test`, then `test.mydomain.com` should point to your servers IP, as also shown in the OP).

Comment: I had manually added my public key to `authorized_hosts` before going through the setup and that screwed things up. I used your comments as a hint and was able to remove the one that was initially. Now it is running through the custom command as intended. Thanks!

Comment: Just making note: I had this occur recently with Dokku 0.7.2 on 16.04